# PHP preg_match_all for new line

Tags: php

i need a data "2.5 (0.5)" and "3.5" 
my pattern is `'/class="match_total_goal_div">.+</s'` 
But it is not working. 
Please help.

```
<div class="match_total_goal_div">
2.5 (0.5) </div>
<div class="match_half_goal_div hide" ">
</div>
</td>
<td class="text-center corner_goal_range">
<div>
<span class="newlabel">N.A.</span>
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="match_total_goal_div">
3.5 </div>
.
.
.
```

Comment: why not by jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to add brackets around your `.+` to capture the desired data. By the way you need a question mark: `.+?`.

Hope this can help you

```
$str = '<div class="match_total_goal_div">
2.5 (0.5) </div>
<div class="match_total_goal_div">
3.5 </div>';

$pattern = '/class="match_total_goal_div">(.+?)</s';

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code to accomplish your goal

```
<?php
    $html = '<div class="match_total_goal_div">
    2.5 (0.5) </div>
    <div class="match_half_goal_div hide">
    </div>
    <td class="text-center corner_goal_range"></td>
    <div>
    <span class="newlabel">N.A.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="match_total_goal_div">
    3.5 </div>';
    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    $DOM->loadHTML($html);
    $finder = new DomXPath($DOM);
    $classname = 'match_total_goal_div';
    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      echo $node->nodeValue."\n";
    }
?>
```

Live demo : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3e645ac56b9f7bf57d4519abd6b1be90ed87945